# Search files with prefix on S3 in Laravel 9

Tags: php, amazon-s3, laravel-9

I'm working on a project that save file on S3. But I've never worked with S3 before.
I want to retrieve the files that match this pattern:  {id}_{YYYYMMDD}.pdf

I could do this `Storage::disk('s3')->files();` with Storage, but I think it's not the solution because there are thousand of files.

I search through topics and this is one of the things I've tried so far:

```
public static function searchS3ByPrefix($path, $prefix) {
        try {
            $storage = Storage::disk('s3');
            $client = $storage->getAdapter()->getClient();     // ** error on this line
            $command = $client->getCommand('ListObjects');
            $command['Bucket'] = $storage->getAdapter()->getBucket();
            $command['Prefix'] = $path . $prefix;
            $result = $client->execute($command);

            return array_column($result['Contents'], 'Key');
        } 
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error($e);
            return [];
        }
    }
```

The error message said that `getClient()` is undefined in `League\Flysystem\AwsS3V3\AwsS3V3Adapter`

Do you have a solution for this? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the line where I commented error, just modify it into this:
`$client = $storage->getClient();`

Note: In my case, the result will be empty if the prefix has slash `/` at the very beginning, so make sure to remove it. For example: `'/data/1_'` will not work, change it to `'data/1_'`